# Does anyone know what kind of pan this is?

Tags: equipment

[image]

I have a friend who has this pan. What is it used for?

Comment: The dished bits with a rim around the top edge in some ways reminds me of a takoyaki pan .. the extra bit from the top is worked in to fill in the sphere as you rotate the takoyaki ... but your friend's pan seems to be flat at the bottom.   Can you give us any clues as to the possible country of origin, or if there are any markings on the pan indicating manufacturer?

Comment: Can you add pictures from different angles, like the profile of the pan?

Comment: And how big is it?

Comment: @Joe Isn't takoyaki usually round, like a ball shape?

Comment: @Cindy : yes.  I don't think that it *is* a takoyaki pan, I'm just thinking that it might be something that gets rolled over and ends up being taller than the pan when it's finished.  (although, there's what looks like a flat bottom in the middle, making it more difficult to roll the whole thing.).  The center depression kinda reminds me of the shape of omurice, though.  Of course, if it didn't have a wooden handle, it could also be used to make a hat-shaped cake.

Comment: @Joe I thought about the shape being like omurice, but never thought they had a pan for it. I mean, that seems like cheating, right? But you are absolutely correct. My hat's off to you! Post it.

Answer (score 14):

Your friend has an omurice pan. Omurice is a type of Japanese omelet. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omurice):

> Omurice or omu-rice (オムライス Omu-raisu) is an example of yōshoku (a Western-influenced style of Japanese cuisine[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGydR.jpg)) consisting of an omelette made with fried rice and usually topped with ketchup.[2][3] With omu and raisu being contractions of the words omelette and rice,[4] the name is an example of Gairaigo. It is a popular dish both commonly cooked at home and often found at western style diners in Japan.
>
> Omurice is said to have originated around the turn of the 20th century[4] at a western style restaurant in Tokyo's Ginza district called Renga-tei, inspired by chakin-zushi.[5] The dish was brought to Korea and Taiwan, and it is popular cuisine[6]. In Japan children, in particular, enjoy omurice, and it is often featured in okosama-ranchi (お子様ランチ) or kids' meals.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGydR.jpg)

This picture shows how it would be used:

[image]

Comment: Huh. Neat. Nice job.